# Error : json string did not start with array or object for icloud

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, icloud, icloud-api

I am working with iCloud first time. I uploaded the data to iCloud database successfully.

I wrote the following code to retrieve the data:

```
[[iCloud sharedCloud] retrieveCloudDocumentWithName:
          @"SessionInfo.plist" completion:
          ^(UIDocument *cloudDocument, NSData *documentData, NSError *error) {

  NSError *error;
  id dict = [NSJSONSerialization
  JSONObjectWithData:documentData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
```

Here dict is nil. Error message is '`json string did not start with array or object for iCloud`'.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749751/download-and-save-icloud-data-in-plist-format-in-document-folder) is very similar -- are you posting from both your and user3305252's account? If this is the case, please merge your question to one and delete the other.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the error message, because that's not an error that `NSJSONSerialization` can return. Most likely the error message was something like `The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format` or `JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.` It's important to include the **exact** error message when asking a question if you want people to know what you're talking about.

**Assuming** that the error matches what I think it matches, the answer is simple: Your `documentData` object does not contain valid JSON. As a result `NSJSONSerialization` can't convert it to a dictionary. The first argument to that method must contain valid JSON data encoded into an `NSData` object.

It's impossible to be certain why this is, since you didn't describe the data you're working with. However since you're using a file name of `SessionInfo.plist`, you're probably working with a property list. **Property lists are not JSON**. Valid property list file formats include XML, binary (undocumented format), and ASCII (obsolete but still readable). None of those are JSON, and none will work with `NSJSONSerialization`.